# How can I use config map parameter in ServiceMonitor spec.endpoints.basicAuth?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, servicemonitor

I am struggling with using basic auth credentials in Service Monitor. Here is what I have tried:

1. Creating Secrets.yaml and using static string as secrets and using the same in basicAuth
   basicAuth:
   password:
   name: username
   key: basic-auth
   username:
   name: password
   key: basic-auth

But I need to get the secrets from banzai cloud vault instead of static string secrets

2. I am also using ConfigMap to fetch the secrets from vault but I am unable to use the same in Secrets.yaml

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
   name: demo
   labels: demo
   data:
   es.basic-user: vault:{{ .Values.vault.secretsEnginePath }}/data/demo#username
   es.basic-pass: vault:{{ .Values.vault.secretsEnginePath }}/data/demo#password
3. Only static secrets are working:

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
   name: basic-auth
   stringData:
   password: demo
   username: demo
   type: Opaque

My objective is to have something from the following:

1. Use secrets from vault for basicAuth credentials
2. Even if secrets.yaml needs to be used then credentials need not be string.
3. If config map parameter can be used

This is my ServiceMonitor:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels: demo
  name: demo
  annotations:
    vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-skip-verify: "true"
    vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-addr: "{{ .Values.vault.url }}"
    vault.security.banzaicloud.io/vault-role: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}-demo"
spec:
  endpoints:
  - honorLabels: true
    port: http
    scheme: https
    path: /_prometheus/metrics
    tlsConfig:
      insecureSkipVerify: true
    basicAuth:
      password:
        name: username
        key: basic-auth
      username:
        name: password
        key: basic-auth
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  selector:
    matchLabels: demo
```